# Backend doesn't respond to HTTP requests

Tags: http, backend

I know that the information that follows is most certainly not enough to solve my problem and I may specify what is needed when and if needed.

The situation is the following. I was programming normally and, as I did, I made a PUT request to my application backend. The browser tab suddenly logged many (like, many) errors concerning different information which I cannot remember due to the fact that it closed itself soon after. Almost at the same time, both VSCode windows I had open and running the backend and frontend of the application closed themselves.

Since then, the backend does not appear to answer any HTTP request made to it. It doesn't get to the point in which the code of the controllers run, for I have put a console.log there and nothing is logged. Similarly, no errors are shown in the console when the request is made. It still connects to an MQTT broker, as it was supposed to.

The Insomnia request loads forever unless I cancel it, and, Insomnia still notices when the connection is reset, giving the

```
Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

error.

Lastly, the frontend created a debug.log file in the project's folder that contain 21 lines that read

```
[0624/203732.834:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(428)] unexpected header
```

with the only difference being the numbers in the start, and, also created a yarn-error.log, a very long log with a line that caught my eye (because it had the word "Error" in it) that reads, among other things,

```
Trace: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked...
```

I have no clue what happened or what I should do.

Comment: Have you tried these calls through any of the rest clients like postman?

Comment: Try formatting your question a bit. Multiple paragraphs are nice, and there's formatting for things like logs and code too.

Comment: @NiteshSharma No. I'll try it then.

Comment: @Evert Ok, I'll do that

Comment: @NiteshSharma I've just downloaded and used Postman to make a request. The result is the same: it loads forever unless I cancel it.

Comment: means there is an issue with backend service in which technology you created that ? Also, have you tried to debug as well ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma I have used Node.js and use Express for the request handling. As for debuging, I don't know how to debug it. Although, now that you have said, a "debug" button over the "scripts" line in my package.json file (I don't know how to use it, however).

Comment: you have to start app first then run your app by clicking debug and then put breakpoints follow the link  [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Comment: @NiteshSharma Ok, then. I'll learn how to debug the code, and, post a comment about what I found out.

Comment: sure all the best

Comment: @NiteshSharma I have debugged the code and I have found nothing of use (it may also be because I didn't do a great job at it). The controller function is never called. I don't even know (and don't know how to know (with the debugger, probably)) if express "activates" or "notices the request" when the request is made.

Comment: @NiteshSharma I don't know what the hell happened, but all this time I was wondering if it was because, although Express was declared in package.json, the code only "assumed it existed" (and, therefore could import from it) but "could not use it". I had tried to run "yarn add express" but it changed nothing. I've just ran "npm install express" and when I tried to run the application, an error said it couldn't find module socket.io. So I ran "yarn add socket.io" and the problem was fixed. I still don't know what happened, but I got to learn how to debug, at least. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run the following:

```
npm install express
```

Comment: Aside from the typo, why will this fix the problem? What in the question indicates that express is missing?

Comment: @JasonAller Do I look like someone who knows why it worked?